# Is there a resource for the correct pronunciation of names of non-English mathematicians (eg, Fresnel, Fermat, Galois)?

Tags: reference-request, pronunciation

English people are bad at mathematics $\implies$ most great mathematicians were not English $\implies$ most important mathematical objects are named after non-English people.

For example:

- Today I discovered that “Fresnel” has a silent “s”. I've been pronouncing it wrong all these decades, because I've only ever read about it in books.
- I read all of *Fermat's Last Theorem* without realising that the “t” is silent.
- The apparently correct way to pronounce “Galios” just blew my mind!
- To this day I still don't know which way is the correct way to pronounce “Gauss”.

Is there some kind of dictionary somewhere which lists the correct pronunciation for all these foreign names? Wikipedia *sometimes* gives the pronunciation (e.g., it claims that Lie algebra is in fact pronounced “lee algebra”). But very frequently it doesn't.

Comment: I can't give you a dictionary, but as a German native: the *au* in Gauß is pronounced like *ou* in out.

Comment: Also, you misspelled Galois, which is kind of funny in this thread. :P

Comment: The search "how to pronounce NAME in LANGUAGE" usually gives satisfactory results. For example, try "how pronounce Józef Wronski in Polish".

Comment: The [Wikipedia article about Gauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss) gives the pronunciation in IPA, plus an audio file. What more could you ask for?

Comment: @awkward Your comment should definitely be an answer.

Comment: @Pedro OK, the comment is now an answer.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The pronunciation of all names you mentioned, and many others (like Euler, Riemann, Lebesgue, etc) can be found in the [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of Mathematics](https://www.google.com.br/books/edition/MCGRAW_HILL_DICTIONARY_OF_MATHEMATICS_2/7UiwB3FNORYC?hl=pt-BR&gbpv=0) in the appropriate entry. For example: Galois group (ˈgalˌwä ˌgrüp).

Answer (score 2):

One source is [Pronunciation of Mathematicians Names](http://pronouncemath.blogspot.com/#).